# After transform image using AffineTransform, photo get low quality

Tags: java, photo, bufferedimage, affinetransform

I'm trying to fixing photo direction using EXIF information, the photo rotated correctly but after rotate they becomes very low quality...My guess is parameter passed during write new image is wrong. Any help appreciated.

[image: Before]
[image: After]

```
//code get Exif information 
 Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(outputFile);
        Directory directory = metadata.getFirstDirectoryOfType(ExifIFD0Directory.class);
        if(directory == null) {
            logger.warn("no EXIF info.");
            outputFile.delete();
            return;
        }
        JpegDirectory jpegDirectory = metadata.getFirstDirectoryOfType(JpegDirectory.class);
        int orientation;
        try {
            orientation = directory.getInt(ExifIFD0Directory.TAG_ORIENTATION);
            if(orientation != 1) {
                //rotate image
                int w = jpegDirectory.getImageWidth();
                int h = jpegDirectory.getImageHeight();
                ImageInformation imageInformation = new ImageInformation(orientation, w, h);
                AffineTransform affineTransform = getExifTransformation(imageInformation);

                InputStream pictureStream = new FileInputStream(outputFile);
                BufferedImage pictureBuffer = ImageIO.read(pictureStream);
                pictureStream.close();
                if (pictureBuffer == null) {
                    logger.warn("The picture buffer parsed is null.");
                }
                pictureBuffer = transformImage(pictureBuffer, affineTransform);


    //code do image transfer
    public static BufferedImage transformImage(BufferedImage image, AffineTransform transform) throws Exception {

    AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(transform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BICUBIC);
    BufferedImage destinationImage = op.createCompatibleDestImage(image,  null );
    Graphics2D g = destinationImage.createGraphics();
    g.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    g.clearRect(0, 0, destinationImage.getWidth(), destinationImage.getHeight());
    destinationImage = op.filter(image, destinationImage);
    return destinationImage;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that the image quality was degraded, most patterns look as sharp as before (see the elk on the milk bottle). However, I would say that the colors where mixed up, and the overall illumination decreased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may solve your problem. According to AffineTransformOp

```
"If destCM is null, an appropriate ColorModel is used; this ColorModel may 
have an alpha channel even if the source ColorModel is opaque."
```

Therefore I suggest the following:

```
AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(transform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BICUBIC);
BufferedImage destinationImage = op.createCompatibleDestImage(image,  null );
destinationImage = op.filter(image, null);
return destinationImage;
```

or even forgo the compatible image:

```
AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(transform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BICUBIC);
BufferedImage destinationImage = op.filter(image, null);
return destinationImage;
```

Also I'm not sure Bicubic is all that important but may not be the problem.

Because the compatible image returns an image with alpha i.e. transparent

this

```
 Graphics2D g = destinationImage.createGraphics();
g.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
g.clearRect(0, 0, destinationImage.getWidth(), destinationImage.getHeight());
```

will put a layer of transparency on the image; the image painted afterward with be fused with the white color.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all the helps:-)
After change transform function to this, problem  solved, not sure why it's the case, gpasch may be right

```
    public static BufferedImage transformImage(BufferedImage image, AffineTransform transform) throws Exception {

    AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(transform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BICUBIC);
    BufferedImage destinationImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(),image.getHeight(), image.getType());
    destinationImage = op.filter(image, destinationImage);
    return destinationImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple and you should use the dimensions expected from the operation:

```
AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(transform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
BufferedImage destinationImage = op.filter(bImage, op.createCompatibleDestImage(bImage, null));
```